# Angular Material 2 in custom component does not render

Tags: angular, angular-material2

For creating a web-app I use angular seed advanced to start with.
I've extended it with angular material 2.
This works very fine as long as I am in 'root'-components.

Ie: I've made a default-layout.component.(ts|html|scss). In the html file I have this code:

```
<md-sidenav-layout class="md-sidenav-container">
    <md-sidenav #start mode="side" opened="true" class="sidenav-left">
        <md-select>
            <md-option>start</md-option>
            <md-option>end</md-option>
        </md-select>
        <np-nav-menu></np-nav-menu>
    </md-sidenav>
    <div class="main-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

The generated md-select  and md-sidenav works like a charm.

But when I try to set md-select in another component (say: np-select-group)
the select is not rendered.

np-select-group.component.html:

```
<md-select>
    <md-option>start</md-option>
    <md-option>end</md-option>
</md-select>
```

default-layout.component.html

```
<md-sidenav-layout class="md-sidenav-container">
        <md-sidenav #start mode="side" opened="true" class="sidenav-left">
            <np-select-group></np-select-group>

            <np-nav-menu></np-nav-menu>
        </md-sidenav>
        <div class="main-content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </md-sidenav-layout>
```

I only see the words "start" and "end" in a row. 
When I look into rendered html, the select is not rendered at lot.

This occurs too with all other material2 components.

Do I have to import some other things into my custom component's ts?

Comment: is `np-select-group.component` part of the same NgModule where the MaterialModule is imported?

Comment: That was the problem indeed. I needed to import MaterialModule in the module for np-select-group. :( How could I overlook this so badly? :-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment: the np-select-group.component is in a different module. 
I needed to import MaterialModule in this NgModule.

group.module.ts:

```
[...]
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [
   GROUP_COMPONENTS
  ],
  providers: [
   GROUP_PROVIDERS
  ],
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
  exports: [
    GROUP_COMPONENTS
  ]
})
export class GroupModule { }
[...]
```